# case when date field is not null with Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

```
Select CASE 
          WHEN eventdate IS NOT NULL
          then 1 
          ELSE 0 
       end as datestatus
FROM table
```

I am running on AWS Redshift tables and I get the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: COALESCE types character varying and integer cannot be matched;
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: are you sure that this statement fails? or what is your question?

Comment: Mary your posted query will work fine every where supported in sql please provide all the necessary information

Comment: @Mary . . . Perhaps your table is a view.